# Defining A Custom Class with Text Input values

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, serialization, flash-builder

I have another question for the masses out there regarding trying to input values from a text input box to a custom class. I currently have a custom class named `Company` with properties that correspond to values in a `MySQL` database.

So I created an input UI on the client application that calls out for Address, Name, Zip, Phone, etc. - Then there is a button to submit to values to the database for creation. Here's my question:

How do I take each individual `textinput.text` property and 'mesh' them all together to a `Company` object to send to the server? The PHP that is written takes in an argument like this:

```
public function createNewCompany (Company $item) { .......
```

So is that even the right way to send them in? Or???

There are a total of 11 things (properties) that need to be submitted.
As usual - any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

-CS

Comment: What is your method of submission?  AMFPHP?  Or ZendAMF?  Or are you using web services or an HTTPService?

Comment: Well - you learn at least one thing new every day - and today I found out that this process is called Serialization - Thanks Ancide!

Comment: @www.Flextras - It's Zend....And I have no idea what I'm using for protocol(HTTP/WebServices/RemoteObject) - I have nothing defined yet (maybe on of my problems?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example I think you'll find helpful :

http://wadearnold.com/blog/zend-amf-links

If you take a peek at that, it's doing the exact type of stuff you're trying to do, very clearly.  I'll summarize of the the basic parts for you...

What you need to do is transfer the input's into a value object and send that object off to the server.

A value object is just an object you create that holds values (great name, eh?)  You map this to an object of similar properties on the back end with the RemoteClass call:

```
package
{
[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="ContactVO")]
public class ContactVO
{
    public var id:int;
    public var firstname:String;
    public var lastname:String;
    public var email:String;
    public var mobile:String;

}
}
```

On the server you have that same value object definition:

```
<?php
class Contact
{
  public $id = 0;
  public $firstname = "";
  public $lastname = "";
  public $email = "";
  public $mobile = "";
}
?>
```

As for the transport, you're going to use a RemoteObject which transports requests to your endpoint:

```
<Declarations>
    <RemoteObject endpoint="http://localhost/" id="myservice" fault="faultHandler(event)" 
        source="ContactDAO" destination="zend">
        <method name="getContacts" result="contactsHandler(event)" />
    </RemoteObject>      
</Declarations>
```

This maps to a method on your backend, in ContactDAO.php in this case :

```
<?php
require_once 'Contact.php';

class ContactDAO
{
  function createContact( $contact )
  {
    ...
  }    
}
?>
```

Comment: That sounds like EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks for your time and assistance Nate...I'm gonna go plug this in right now and give it a try. I really do appreciate the time! I also went and got those sample files and as I looked through them briefly - it looked like I may be able to use them for some 'guidance' here in the near future. Thank you again!!!

Comment: Yep...Just plugged it in and that WAS the ticket!!! I can't thank you enough Nate. I don't know if I can add points to your status other than just clicking 'accepted answer' - but if there is I'd give you a ton of em right now - LoL! Thank you again...I LOVE this site because of people like you...

Comment: heh, only accepting and upvoting i think :P  but no problem - we all do it cause we enjoy it (i just joined about a week ago and seem addicted)   :D